# Is it possible to connect to several backends with one ipython-qtconsole frontend?

Tags: python, ipython

I am just discovering how great ipython-qtconsole is. I mainly like the block editing, but also syntax highlighting, inline graphs and how I can use it to connect to remote computers over ssh.

Since ipython-qtconsole has tabs, it seems like I should be able to connect one frontend to multiple existing backends, one for each tab, but I can't find any documentation for that. Is it possible?

EDIT:
I understand that I can start new local kernels and that I can connect to one existing kernel on startup, but after I have started up, can I connect to other existing kernels? These kernels will be remote over ssh, so I assume that I need to start them outside of ipython-qtconsole.

Comment: I'm not sure if the UI for connecting a new tab to an existing kernel is implemented - if you don't get an answer here, someone on the ipython-user mailing list will know.

Comment: The UI for "new tab with *specified* existing kernel" doesn't exist at the moment, but it should be easy to add.